# FindMaximum starts with a point outside the range

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I try to find a maximum of a function using:

```
FindMaximum[{Log[81 x + 19] + Log[80 y + 20] + Log[60 (1 - x - y) + 40], 
            0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1, x + y < 1}, {x, y}]
```

I get an error message:

```
FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value -11.1219-3.14159 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {0.9,0.9}.
```

Sure, it is not a real number since $60(1-x-y)-40<0$. But why did FindMaximum even tried these values? They are outside the range $x+y<1$!

Is there a way to tell FindMaximum to only look inside the range?

Comment: As an alternative, `NMaximize` works with your system with no errors. Additionally, if you provide a better starting point than the one selected automatically, `FindMaximum` works as well: `FindMaximum[{Log[81 x + 19] + Log[80 y + 20] + 
   Log[60 (1 - x - y) + 40], 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1, 
  x + y < 1}, {{x, 0.5}, {y, 0.4}}]` returns `{11.8731, {x -> 0.48251, y -> 0.467078}}`.

Comment: @MarcoB yes, NMaximize works, but since my goal functions are convex, I think that FindMaximum should work
 faster.   I also tried to change the initial values and it worked, but I do not understand why Mathematica tries values outside the range at all?

Comment: I don't know why MMA can't find a starting value, but you could provide a starting value. `FindMaximum[{Log[81 x + 19] + Log[80 y + 20] + 
   Log[60 (1 - x - y) + 40], 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 
  x + y <= 1}, {{x, 0}, {y, 0} } ]` evaluates the result without error message.

Comment: Maybe choosing the starting point for numerical optimization algorithms is too vital to leave it to a dull machine? ;)